# Avoid recursion with long polling

Tags: javascript, angularjs, recursion, long-polling

I'm new with Angular and I'm doing basic long polling like this (and let's assume the request always succeeds)

```
theCtrl.getDefis = function() {
    $http.get("services.php")
    .success(function(data){
        //process here
        //then
        theCtrl.getDefis();
    });
}
```

I'm wondering if there is any issue with that. I'm worried about recursion and the stack : if this is called thousand of times, will it be ok ?

I'm not speaking about performance (and I don't want to use websockets :) ). I just want to know if I can do what I'm doing or, if it won't work, what other choice I have.

Thanks.

Comment: It's totally fine. You're not doing actual recursion on the stack, as this happens from an asynchronous callback.

Comment: it's not recursive, it's just self-dispatching.